# Installing virtualbox on elementaryOS 6. Failing to start virtualbox service

Tags: virtualbox, odin

Having trouble installing Virtualbox on Odin. I installed via apt, by entering

`sudo apt install virtualbox`

The installation output I got was the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
  vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
The following NEW packages will be installed
  virtualbox virtualbox-qt
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 43.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 172 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt Mirrorlist [896 B]
Get:2 http://mirror.pulsant.com/sites/ubuntu-archive focal-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox amd64 6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2 [21.5 MB]
Get:3 https://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-qt amd64 6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2 [21.7 MB]
Fetched 43.2 MB in 11s (4,036 kB/s)                                                                                                                         
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
(Reading database ... 155450 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox_6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-qt_6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2) ...
Setting up virtualbox (6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2) ...
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-10-22 21:10:46 BST; 4ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 4105 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 22 21:10:46 TUXEDO-eOS systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Oct 22 21:10:46 TUXEDO-eOS virtualbox[4105]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Oct 22 21:10:46 TUXEDO-eOS virtualbox[4105]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Oct 22 21:10:46 TUXEDO-eOS virtualbox[4105]:    ...fail!
Oct 22 21:10:46 TUXEDO-eOS systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 22 21:10:46 TUXEDO-eOS systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 22 21:10:46 TUXEDO-eOS systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
```

Since eOS 6 is based on Ubuntu 20.04, I tried installing virtualbox the same way on a Ubuntu 20.04 installation. I was able to install virtualbox without any trouble. What is wrong here? I thought it is the same base system.

Has anyone had the same problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Iḿ not able to install Virtualbox on Jólnir version, I receive the following message:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-6.1: Depende: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
Depende: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
Recomienda: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
Recomienda: linux-headers-generic but it is not installable or
linux-headers-generic-pae but it is not installable or
linux-headers-686-pae but it is not installable or
linux-headers-amd64 but it is not installable or
linux-headers-2.6-686 but it is not installable or
linux-headers-2.6-amd64 but it is not installable or
linux-headers but it is not installable
Recomienda: gcc but it is not installable
Recomienda: make but it is not installable or
build-essential but it is not installable or
dpkg-dev but it is not installable
Recomienda: binutils but it is not installable
Recomienda: pdf-viewer but it is not installable